# How to prevents read from happening whenever I am doing a write?

Tags: java, multithreading, countdownlatch, atomicreference

I am trying to implement lock by which I don't want to have reads from happening whenever I am doing a write.

Below is my `ClientData` class in which I am using `CountDownLatch` -

```
public class ClientData {

    private static final AtomicReference<Map<String, Map<Integer, String>>> primaryMapping = new AtomicReference<>();
    private static final AtomicReference<Map<String, Map<Integer, String>>> secondaryMapping = new AtomicReference<>();
    private static final AtomicReference<Map<String, Map<Integer, String>>> tertiaryMapping = new AtomicReference<>();

    // should this be initialized as 1?
    private static final CountDownLatch hasBeenInitialized = new CountDownLatch(1) 

    public static Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> getPrimaryMapping() {
        try {
            hasBeenInitialized.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }

        return primaryMapping.get();
    }

    public static void setPrimaryMapping(Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> map) {
        primaryMapping.set(map);
        hasBeenInitialized.countDown();
    }

    public static Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> getSecondaryMapping() {
        try {
            hasBeenInitialized.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }

        return secondaryMapping.get();
    }       

    public static void setSecondaryMapping(Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> map) {
        secondaryMapping.set(map);
        hasBeenInitialized.countDown();
    }

    public static Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> getTertiaryMapping() {
        try {
            hasBeenInitialized.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }

        return tertiaryMapping.get();
    }       

    public static void setTertiaryMapping(Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> map) {
        tertiaryMapping.set(map);
        hasBeenInitialized.countDown();
    }       
}
```

**PROBLEM STATEMENT:-**

I need to wait on the `get` calls on three `AtomicReferences` I have in the above code. Once all the writes has been done on the three `AtomicReferences` I have with the `set` call, then I would allow making the call to three getters which I have.

So I decided to use `CountDownLatch` which I have initialized as `1`? Do I need to initialize it to `3`? And every time before I do the first set on a new update, should I need to resetup the countdown latch back to 3? Because I will be setting those three `AtomicReferences` in separate three statements.

I am guess there is something wrong in my above code?

**NOTE:-**

I will be setting like this from some other class -

```
ClientData.setPrimaryMapping(primaryTables);
ClientData.setSecondaryMapping(secondaryTables);
ClientData.setTertiaryMapping(tertiaryTables);
```

Some other threads has to read the data from these `AtomicReferences` once they have been set.

**Update:-**

Below is my background thread code which will get the data from the URL, parse it and store it in a `ClientData`class variable.

```
public class TempScheduler {

    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

        public void startScheduler() {
            final ScheduledFuture<?> taskHandle = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                try {
                    callServers();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                }
            }, 0, 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        }
    }

    // call the servers and get the data and then parse 
    // the response.
    private void callServers() {
        String url = "url";
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
        parseResponse(response);

    }

    // parse the response and store it in a variable
    private void parseResponse(String response) {
        //...       
        ConcurrentHashMap<String, Map<Integer, String>> primaryTables = null;
        ConcurrentHashMap<String, Map<Integer, String>> secondaryTables = null;
        ConcurrentHashMap<String, Map<Integer, String>> tertiaryTables = null;

        //...

        // store the data in ClientData class variables which can be
        // used by other threads
    ClientData.setPrimaryMapping(primaryTables);
    ClientData.setSecondaryMapping(secondaryTables);
    ClientData.setTertiaryMapping(tertiaryTables);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier and more readable to just use the `synchronized` keyword here?

Comment: Please post code for entry point method `main`.

Comment: Have you considered [`ReadWriteLock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html)? This is exactly what it is designed for.

Comment: What about if `ClientData.setPrimaryMapping(primaryTables);` is called three times simultaneously?

Comment: @Braj: It won't be called three times simultaneously for sure. I have updated the code where I am setting these three AtomicReferences.

Comment: Have you tried having set `CountDownLatch` to 3?

Comment: I still don't understand why they're atomic references when from the application perspective they clearly aren't. If you had a reference instead to a single container object with your three variables as fields, then you could use atomic references without a problem.

Comment: @Braj: I can try using `CountDownLatch` to `3` but the question is what it should be in general? As I am not multithreading expert so I am having some confusion. In my case, I need to wait on `getPrimaryMapping` if any writes are happening to `setPrimaryMapping`. Similarly, I need to wait on `getSecondaryMapping` if any writes are happening to `setSecondaryMapping`. Also, I need to wait on `getTertiaryMapping` if any writes are happening to `setTertiaryMapping`.

Comment: @RussellZahniser: That's a good suggestion. If I am using `ReentrantLock` for my use case, then that should be fine right? I have never used lock before so learning some stuff on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to treat all 3 variables independently (i.e. getting tertiary does not need to wait for primary to be set), which is how I read your question, you simply need to create 1 countdown latch for each map. Each setter counts down the respective latch for the variable being set. Each getter calls await on the respective latch.

Comment: In my case, I need to wait on `getPrimaryMapping` if any writes are happening to `setPrimaryMapping`. Similarly, I need to wait on `getSecondaryMapping` if any writes are happening to `setSecondaryMapping`. Also, I need to wait on `getTertiaryMapping` if any writes are happening to `setTertiaryMapping`. So in that case also, it should be set to 1? If yes, then can you explain why just for my knowledge?

Comment: You need one countdown latch for each mapping (as they are all being tracked independently). This means 3 countdown latches all with a value of 1. The value needs to be one because you are only waiting for one countdown event to occur.

Comment: Makes sense now. Is there any way, I can have one countdown latch instead of having three? I guess for this, I might need to change how I am constructing ClientData object. right?

Comment: If you want to track 3 events independently of each other, it will require 3 latches. If you changed to have a single setter method which took all 3 mappings (either directly or with a wrapping class as suggested by @bizclop) then you would only need a single latch to countdown after setting.

Answer (score 0):

This setup is a complete overkill IMO.

Here's an alternative which works correctly and is far more simpler:

```
public class MappingContainer {
     private final Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> primaryMapping;
     private final Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> secondaryMapping;
     private final Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> tertiaryMapping;

     // + constructor and getters
}

public class ClientData {
    private static volatile MappingContainer mappingContainer;

    // regular setters and getters
}

public class TempScheduler {
//...
    private void parseResponse(String response) {
        //...       
        ConcurrentHashMap<String, Map<Integer, String>> primaryTables = null;
        ConcurrentHashMap<String, Map<Integer, String>> secondaryTables = null;
        ConcurrentHashMap<String, Map<Integer, String>> tertiaryTables = null;

        //...

        // store the data in ClientData class variables which can be
        // used by other threads
        ClientData.setMappingContainer( new MappingContainer( primaryTables, secondaryTables, tertiaryTables );
    }
}
```

Latches and atomic references should be left to when the simpler constructs won't cut it. In particular, a latch is good if you have to count to any N events (and not 3 specific ones), and an atomic reference is only useful if you use the compare-and-set or get-and-set idiom.

Comment: Thanks. In your example how does Volatile helps here? Suppose if I start my main application, then will it wait on the get call or not? Because it might be possible set call is taking some time because it is done by a background thread so we don't know how much time will it take to parse the response and set it in the ClientData class? So then in that case, first get call will fail right?

Comment: I see, that's slightly different then. If you want to block the getter until the setter is called, use a latch instead of the `volatile` keyword. Just one latch, counting down from 1 (because you want the setter to be called once). An even nicer solution would be to only construct the `ClientData` object itself when all the tables become available.

Comment: Atleast we agree on something. :). And In my case, as I have three different set calls for each tables from the background thread as shown above. Then also, countdownlatch should be `1` in that scenario? Or you are saying, I should construct `ClientData` object only when all the tables are available and then in that case, I can use latch initialized to `1`?

Comment: If you construct the `ClientData` when all the tables are available, you won't need a latch at all or indeed any other mechanism. There is an implicit memory barrier at the end of each constructor call ensuring that `final` fields initialised within them are visible to everyone.